# singular or plural: objects following "sometimes"

Tags: grammar

I would like to ask a question to native English speakers.  Could you tell which sentense is right and its reason?

a) I sometimes go to a museum.
b) I sometimes go to museums.

My question is whether we should take plural or singular object when we use "sometimes."

Thank you.

Comment: They can both be right depending on the context.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I would like to ask in what context these sentenses differ.

Comment: @MGK if you visit multiple museums, then it would be "sometimes I go to museums". Additionally, it is what you might say if somebody ever asks you "do you ever go to museums?"

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment.  Does this "multiple" mean "going to multiple museums at one time" or "going to several museum"?

Answer (score 1):

> a) I sometimes go to **a** museum.

You would say this when you often go to one particular museum (e.g., the Museum of Modern Art). You can also say this when you go to any museum on a particular occasion.

> When I am depressed, I sometimes go to a museum or an empty theater.

The other one

> b) I sometimes go to museums.

can be said when you visit multiple museums, both in a single occasion and in different ones.

When I go to NYC, I sometimes go to museums, parks, and libraries.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanation.  I have finally got it!

Comment: +1 BUT, if it is just one particular museum (e.g. the Museum of Modern Art), it wouldn't normally take the indefinite article. If one's listener was likely to be aware of which museum it was, one could use the definite article - *I often go to the museum*. If not then it might sound a bit clumsy if you didn't mention the name of the museum. Incidentally, I am a little concerned at any possible implication that museums have some connection with depression, or the relief thereof!